# Dynamically allocated structures are well initialised?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, language-lawyer

For POD structure, could `new Demo_Class[CONST_NUMBER]()` guarantee the dynamically allocated structures are well initialised(i.e. not garbage) ***in C++11 and afterwards***?

It would be appreciated that if somebody shed the light on the **detailed rules about the initialization the POD structure array**.

There are posts about base types, say `new int{}` and etc. But there is no direct answer about POD structures.

What more, most posts does not mention C++11 and afterwards at all.

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to eerorika's for the repid answer.
As per the said answer, which says that[emphasise mine]:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:

> otherwise, ***the object is zero-initialized***.

How to fully understand that? The struct\class may has many member variables with different types. Does it mean every member variable would be the object is zero-initialized? For example:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;inty;
}; 

struct Demo
{
    Point pt; 
    double* ptr; 
    std::string str;
};.
```

Comment: I would argue that the bigger problem is the use of `new[]` to begin with. ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You mean to try `std::vector` and alike first?

Comment: On a related note, also see the difference between `make_unique` and `make_unique_for_overwrite`
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique

Comment: @Den-Jason Sorry, I can't see any relation with this question.

Comment: Yes, `std::vector` should be the default choice for a container if there aren't any other specific requirements. Or `std::array` if the size is known at run-time and won't change (and not too big).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's a good idea indeed. But for me, I have to use `new[]` to provide corresponding resources to the user(caller) now and then.

Comment: If you need a raw non-owning pointer, you can easily get that from a vector as well, using its `data` function. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There are difficulties in using `vector`.  The user/caller would aquire\create and relase\destory the resource now and then. And how many resources are needed is not known in advance.

Comment: @john the use of smart pointers would be another option if you don't wish to use vectors or such-like.  C++20 now also provides an option "for overwrite" such that if you're allocating a buffer to read a file into, then you may specifically _not_ want it to be zero-initialised.

Answer (score 5):

> For POD structure, could `new Demo_Class[CONST_NUMBER]()` guarantee the dynamically allocated structures are well initialised(i.e. not garbage) in C++11 and afterwards?

It has been guaranteed at least since C++03 when value initialisation was introduced (probably also before through older default initialisation rules). The guarantee hasn't been removed in C++11 nor afterwards.

Standard quotes from latest draft:

> [dcl.init.general]
>
> - If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.
>
> ---
>
> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), then
>
>   - if T has either no default constructor ([class.default.ctor]) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
>   - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.
>
> ---
>
> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - if T is a scalar type ([basic.types.general]), the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal 0 (zero) to T;84
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, its padding bits ([basic.types.general]) are initialized to zero bits and each non-static data member, each non-virtual base class subobject, and, if the object is not a base class subobject, each virtual base class subobject is zero-initialized;
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, its padding bits ([basic.types.general]) are initialized to zero bits and the object's first non-static named data member is zero-initialized;
> - if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
> - if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

---

P.S. Avoid using allocating `new`. Consider using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Is there a reference in the standard to this?

Comment: @Den-Jason See edit.

Comment: @eerorika > *** the object is zero-initialized*** How to fully understand that? The struct\class may has many member variables with different types. Does it mean every member variable would be  the object is zero-initialized? For example, `struct Point{int x;inty;}; struct Demo{Point pt; double* ptr; std::string str;};`.

Comment: @John `*** the object is zero-initialized*** How to fully understand that?` See edit.

Comment: @eerorika The quotation from `cppreference` (I guess) is obscure for beginners, especially for the people whose mother language are not English. Could you please give some explanation for the said example?

Comment: More like open-std.org, for example: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf

Comment: There's a more definitive list here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links

Comment: I also would like to see a resource for "the C++ standard in plain English" (_as opposed to "C++ in plain English"_)

Comment: @Den-Jason That would be a good book title.